# Merging .CSV files into one Master Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, csv, merge

I have multiple .CSV files holding my data. I'm trying to merge them into one master sheet.

The macro stops after opening the first .CSV file in the series. It doesn't error.

There's still a good amount of code I have to write, such as identifying specific columns and rows and grabbing that particular data from each of the sheets.

I have this setup as a template.

I transferred the code to a fresh workbook and it still didn't give me anything.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    mergeData
End Sub

Sub mergeData()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Our FileSystem Objects.
    Dim objFs As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim file As Object
    
    'Show a pop up to select a folder.
    Dim sPath As String
    sPath = chooseFolder()
    
    Set objFs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFs.GetFolder(sPath)       ' The folder path.
    
    Dim iCnt As Integer
    iCnt = 1
    
    ' Loop through all the files in the folder.
    For Each file In objFolder.Files
    
        Dim objSrc As Workbook      ' The source.
        Set objSrc = Workbooks.Open(file.Path, True, True)
        
        Dim iTotalRows As Integer   ' The total used range in the source file.
        iTotalRows = objSrc.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
        
        Dim iTotalCols As Integer   ' Now, get the total columns in the source.
        iTotalCols = objSrc.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count
        
        Dim iRows, iCols As Integer
        
        ' Read data from source and copy in the master file.
        For iRows = 1 To iTotalRows
            For iCols = 1 To iTotalCols
                Application.Workbooks(1).ActiveSheet.Cells(iRows, iCols) = _
                  objSrc.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRows, iCols)
                ' Note: It will read data in "Sheet1" of the source file.
            Next iCols
        Next iRows
        
        iRows = 0
        
        ' Get the name of the file (I'll name the active sheet with the filename).
        Dim sSheetName As String
        sSheetName = Replace(objSrc.Name, ".csv", "")          ' Assuming the files are .xlsx files.
        
        ' Close the source file (the file from which its copying the data).
        objSrc.Close False
        Set objSrc = Nothing
        
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .ActiveSheet.Name = sSheetName           ' Rename the sheet.
            iCnt = iCnt + 1
            
            If iCnt > .Worksheets.Count Then
                ' Create or add a new sheet after the last sheet.
                .Sheets.Add After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
            End If
            
            .Worksheets(iCnt).Activate      ' Go to the next sheet.
        End With
    Next
ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

' Open file dialog box to select a folder.
Function chooseFolder() As String
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    With fd
        .Filters.Clear
        .Title = "Select an Excel File"
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.csv?", 1
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        
        Dim sPath As String
    
        If .Show = True Then
            chooseFolder = fd.InitialFileName  ' Get the folder path.
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Comment out the error handler and see what happens.

Comment: Usually, the (single) csv sheet is not named "sheet1" as you try in `iTotalRows = objSrc.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.rows.count`. It is named exactly as the csv file, without extension. Please, try using `iTotalRows = objSrc.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.rows.count`. Then, `Workbooks(1).ActiveSheet` is a strange construction. If you have a `Personal.xlsb` workbook it will be chosen. Is really this workbook the one you want? Besides that, No need of iteration, `iTotalRows`, `iTotalColumns`, you can simple copy the whole `UsedRange` at once.

Comment: `With objSrc.Worksheets(1).UsedRange`  
            `Workbooks(1).ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(.rows.count, .Columns.count).Value = .Value`
        `End With`  Then which is/should be `ActiveWorkbook` when use it as `With ActiveWorkbook` after closing the csv file?

Comment: Aren't there only csv files in the folder you choose? If not, using the above method your code will try opening all files, not only csv type. For only csv type you should use `Dir`...

Comment: Hey Fane, there's only .CSV files in the folder I'm selecting. Will be that way each time. And I was hoping to actually merge them in an already existing template. The original question and code wasn't nearly as accurate or defined as I should have had it. Apologies for that. Attempted the Answer provided by VBasic this morning and it looks like it's pretty close to what I'm aiming for. Will also look into trying your stuff for my own reference. I still have a lot to learn, as can be seen very clearly!

Comment: Hey Tim, commented out the error handles as you had recommended and attempted to run the code. Giving me the following error:
Run-time error '6':
Overflow
Fairly positive there's no virus on my computer causing the issue. Unsure on if there could be a hardware/software issue however. Maybe even a memory problem for this little ole' laptop? Not sure as VBasic2008's solution allowed me to run that macro. Might be outside the range of values? I'm unsure. Will probably be working on VBasic2008's solution, as it is very near exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: So, Tim, I think I figured out my issue with it and why it wasn't processing and instead was giving me the runtime error. Re-looking back at the code, it's stated for the system when accessing the data to transfer:
`Dim iTotalRows As Integer` and `Dim iTotalCols As Integer` brings the total data numbers up to 1007055. The .CSV file is a large data aquisition file for some pressure transducers/flow rate monitors at a very fast scan rate. 
Rows: 90935. Columns: AO
I imagine it was tripping it as too much for the ole' integer to handle, while VBasic had it set as Long for their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy CSV Files to a New Workbook

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    CopyCsvFilesToNewWorkbook
End Sub


Sub CopyCsvFilesToNewWorkbook()
     
    ' Select the source folder path.
    Dim sPath As String: sPath = GetSelectedFolderPath
    If Len(sPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' dialog canceled
    
    Debug.Print "Folder Path: """ & sPath & """"
    
    ' Write the CSV file paths to an array.
    Dim CsvFilePaths As Variant: CsvFilePaths = FilePathsToArray(sPath, "*.csv")
    If IsEmpty(CsvFilePaths) Then Exit Sub ' no files found
    
    Debug.Print "CSV File Paths"
    Debug.Print Join(CsvFilePaths, vbLf)
    
    ' Copy the CSV files to a new workbook.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = CsvFilesToNewWorkbook(CsvFilePaths)
    If dwb Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Debug.Print "The new workbook '" & dwb.Name & "' contains " _
        & dwb.Worksheets.Count & " worksheets."
    
    ' Continue with saving the workbook... 'dwb.SaveAs...'
    
End Sub

Function GetSelectedFolderPath( _
    Optional ByVal InitialFolderPath As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal DialogTitle As String = "Browse", _
    Optional ByVal DialogButtonName As String = "OK") _
As String
    
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim Canceled As Boolean
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = DialogTitle
        .ButtonName = DialogButtonName
        Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
        If Len(InitialFolderPath) > 0 Then
            FolderPath = InitialFolderPath
            If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep
            .InitialFileName = FolderPath
        End If
        If .Show Then
            FolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
            If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep
        Else
            Canceled = True
        End If
    End With
    
    If Canceled Then
        MsgBox "Dialog canceled.", vbExclamation, "GetSelectedFolderPath"
        Exit Function
    End If

    GetSelectedFolderPath = FolderPath

End Function

Function FilePathsToArray( _
    ByVal SourceFolderPath As String, _
    Optional ByVal FilePattern As String = "*.*") _
As Variant
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim fsoFolder As Object: Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(SourceFolderPath)
    Dim LCaseFilePattern As String: LCaseFilePattern = LCase(FilePattern)
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim fsoFile As Object
    Dim FilePath As String
    
    For Each fsoFile In fsoFolder.Files
        FilePath = fsoFile.Path
        If LCase(FilePath) Like LCaseFilePattern Then
            dict(FilePath) = Empty
        End If
    Next fsoFile
    
    If dict.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    FilePathsToArray = dict.Keys

End Function

' This method is written as a function
' to return a reference to the new workbook.
Function CsvFilesToNewWorkbook( _
    ByVal CsvFilePaths As Variant) _
As Workbook
' It is assumed that none of the CSV files are open in the current application
' i.e. if a file is open, modified but not saved, this procedure
' will copy the modified file but will also close it without saving the changes.
' If a file is open in another application, it might not get copied.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim swb As Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim n As Long
    Dim FilesCount As Long
    Dim FilePath As String
    
    For n = LBound(CsvFilePaths) To UBound(CsvFilePaths)
        FilePath = CsvFilePaths(n)
        On Error Resume Next
            Set swb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath, True, True)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not swb Is Nothing Then ' workbook is open
            Set sws = swb.Worksheets(1) ' the one and only
            FilesCount = FilesCount + 1
            If FilesCount = 1 Then ' the first source workbook
                ' Copy the worksheet to a new workbook.
                sws.Copy ' creates a new single-worksheet workbook
                ' Reference this new workbook, the destination workbook.
                Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
            Else ' all source workbooks but the first
                ' Copy the source worksheet to the destination workbook.
                sws.Copy After:=dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count)
            End If
            swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Set swb = Nothing ' reset
        'Else ' workbook is not open; do nothing
        End If
    Next n
    
    If Not dwb Is Nothing Then
        'dwb.Saved = True ' to easily close while testing
        Set CsvFilesToNewWorkbook = dwb
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    'MsgBox "Copied " & FilesCount & "(" & n & ")" & " CSV file" _
        & IIf(FilesCount = 1, "", "s") & " to a new workbook.", _
        IIf(FilesCount = 0, vbExclamation, vbInformation), _
        "CsvFilesToNewWorkbook"
    
End Function
```

Comment: Hey VBasic, worked like a charm. I am wondering what would be the easiest way to have the macro send it to a specific template? I should have been more clear in my original post and I apologize for that. I want to be able to grab the data from the .CSV files and send it to a report template. From this report template, that data will be grabbed to fill out various graphs and information for the data (i.e. RPM at 10BAR, 20BAR, 30BAR pressure. This will all be done by the calculation feature).
Any advice on how to get it to merge to an already created template instead of creating a new workbook?